# Any way to make properties of an object to appear in a particular order when inspecting in VS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a  legacy project where I can often see model classes that have up to 100 properties and while debugging I'd like to see them in a particular order as it's an ordered sequence of data. Is there any sort of an attribute that can make Visual Studio debugger to display them in a particular order instead of sorting them by names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **DebuggerDisplayAttribute** class to customise debugger description. Please read about it in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you append that attribute to certain class you can define how you want to see description during debugging.

One example from MSDN. Here `value` and `key` are will be more visible during debugging:

> ```
> [DebuggerDisplay("{value}", Name = "{key}")]
> internal class KeyValuePairs
> {
>     private IDictionary dictionary;
>     private object key;
>     private object value;
>
>     public KeyValuePairs(IDictionary dictionary, object key, object value)
>     {
>         this.value = value;
>         this.key = key;
>         this.dictionary = dictionary;
>     }
> }
> ```

Here will be easier to see value and key during debugging.

You can consider **[DebuggerBrowsableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** which determine what  will debugger display certain members. You can even hide some members.

Here is some example of [DebuggerBrowsableAttribute](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DebuggerBrowsable.aspx):

```
public class User
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Collapsed)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
    public FullName Name { get; set; }

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

As you see property `HashedPassword` will be hidden from debugging.

Also, you can use [Watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) window in Visual Studio and configure your variable which you want to track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute to control how data is displayed in the tooltip whilst debugging e.g.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Age = {Age}, Name = '{Name}'")]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

For reference:

- [Using the DebuggerDisplay Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)
- [DebuggerDisplay attribute best practices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices/)